# Кастомный балун для карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Всем привет. Задача такая. При клике на метку, появляется кастомный балун, который не зависит от метки. 
Пример:

[image: Кастомный балун]

Весь рунет перешарил, даже похожего не нашел. Подскажите кто сталкивался.

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout

Comment: Он прикреплен к метке

Comment: В таком случае можно сверстать свой блок-балун и абсолютно его спозиционировать относительно блока с картой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно сверстать собственный элемент управления, в котором выводить данные объекта вместо балуна.

В песочнице есть [пример такого решения](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_control?from=SO).