# Кастомизация балуна метки

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите, как добавить изображение в балун?

Создаю кастомный кластеризатор:

```
var places = [];
groups.forEach(function (grp) {
    grp.items.forEach(function (plc) {
        places.push(plc)
    });
});
// Создаем собственный макет с информацией о выбранном геообъекте.
var customItemContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    // Флаг "raw" означает, что данные вставляют "как есть" без экранирования html.
    '<h2 class=ballon_header>{{ properties.balloonContentHeader|raw }}</h2>' +
    '<img class=balloon_img>{{properties.balloonImage|raw }}</img>'+
    '<div class=ballon_body>{{ properties.balloonContentBody|raw }}</div>' +
    '<div class=ballon_footer>{{ properties.balloonContentFooter|raw }}</div>'
);

var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
    // Устанавливаем режим открытия балуна. 
    // В данном примере балун никогда не будет открываться в режиме панели.
    clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0,
    // Устанавливаем размер макета контента балуна (в пикселях).
    clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 500,
    // Устанавливаем собственный макет.
    clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: customItemContentLayout,
    // Устанавливаем ширину левой колонки, в которой располагается список всех геообъектов кластера.
    clusterBalloonLeftColumnWidth: 120
});

// Заполняем кластер геообъектами со случайными позициями.
getPointData = function (index) {
        return {
        balloonImage: places[index].img,
        balloonContentHeader: places[index].name,
        balloonContentBody: places[index].Body,
        balloonContentFooter: places[index].Footer,
        clusterCaption: '<strong>' + places[index].name + '</strong>'
    }; 
},
getPointOptions = function () {
   return {
       preset: 'islands#redIcon'
   };
},
points = [];
groups.forEach(function (grp) {
   grp.items.forEach(function (plc) {
       points.push(
           plc.center
       );
   });
});
geoObjects = [];

for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
    geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(points[i], getPointData(i), 
    getPointOptions());
}
clusterer.add(geoObjects);
myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
    checkZoomRange: true
});
```

Данные координат и данных для меток тянутся из другого .js файла который имеет вид

```
var groups = [
    {           style: "islands#redIcon",
            items: [
            {
                center: [50.621523, 36.578564],
                name: "Корпус №1",
                Header: "Корпус №1",
                Body: "<p>Факультет математики и естественнонаучного образования;</p> <p>Институт инженерных технологий и естественных наук - инженерно-физическое направление;</p> <p><strong>Приемная комиссия</strong></p>",
                img: '<img src="image/logo_name.jpg" />'
            },
            {
                center: [50.621442, 36.577685],
                name: "Корпус №2",
                Header: "Корпус №2",
                Body:"Институт педагогический;<p> Факультет иностранных языков",
                img: '<img src="image/logo_name.jpg" />'
            },
```

Проблема в том, что стили применяются к кластеризированным меткам, а если они находятся отдельно, то изображение и стили не применяются.
Может быть решением является создание отдельного макета для единичного балуна? или как по другому это можно организовать?

Comment: Мне кажется про балун уже тут вопросы были.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821503/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b например

Comment: это не относится к моему вопросу. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как при создании кластеризатора, иметь аналогичное отображение данных и в обычной метке. в данный момент они разнятся

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ сделать балун с фотографией, это задать `balloonContentBody`.

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.733835, 37.588227],
    zoom: 12,
    controls: []
  });

  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(myMap.getCenter(), {
    balloonContentBody: [
      '<address>',
      '<strong>Офис Яндекса в Москве</strong>',
      '<br/>',
      'Адрес: 119021, Москва, ул. Льва Толстого, 16',
      '<br/>',
      'Подробнее: <a href="https://company.yandex.ru/">https://company.yandex.ru</a>',
      '<br/>',
      '<img src="http://mis.mixmarket.biz/r/200/65735/149827303.jpg"/>',
      '</address>'
    ].join('')
  }, {
    preset: 'islands#redDotIcon'
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
  myPlacemark.balloon.open();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: То есть, вы предлагаете сначала сделать балун, а потом уже его кластеризировать?

Comment: Если картинка должна быть в балуне объекта, то её нужно настраивать как balloonContentBody на уровне объекта.

Comment: она должна быть и в кластеризированном балуне и в обычном балуне метки. В кластер выводится и цепляются стили для описания и т.д., а вот для балуна метки нет

Comment: https://codepen.io/folayt/project/editor/XLGbOo# 
Вот что есть в данный момент. необходимо чтобы информация выводилась одинаково в обоих случаях

Comment: Посмотрите [этот пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_balloon?from=SO) - там в json файле заданы данные для меток, где к каждой прописан `balloonContent`; в итоге на карте этот контент отображается для меток, независимо от того кластеризованы они сейчас или нет. Я предлагаю вам также для объектов задать `balloonContentBody` и сразу с картинкой

Comment: А чтобы в json отрисовать полигон нужно прописывать так?
{"type": "Feature", "id": 11, "geometry": {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[ [50.622009273633964, 36.578889376590396],...
]}, "options":{"strokeWidth": 1,"fillColor": "#00FF00"}}