# Макет пользовательского балуна не доступен для панели. Решение?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Требуется изменить балун-панель. А именно добавить border-radius,margin,padding.

Свойство ballonLayout игнорируется при `balloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity`.
Каким образом я смогу задать пользовательский вид балуна-панели?

https://tech.yandex.com/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan - данный пример не помогает, так как генерируется обычный балун на позиции маркера.

Видел такое решение, но выглядит немного костыльно [Кастомный балун для карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821503/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B)

Comment: Балун-панель так кастомизировать не получится, создавайте кастомную панель, [как в этом примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/sidebar?from=SO)

Comment: @Reni спасибо. Видимо придется